# are transform : scale(x , y) and width and height same?

Tags: css

so I was just wondering **transform: scale()** does the same work as **height** and **width** property does as they both increase the x and y of an element

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.

`width` and `height` are properties that affect the size of the element's box. You can learn more about the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) on MDN. If you change the size of an element's box, it can affect the disposition of its content, parent, and siblings.

`transform` lets you apply graphical effects to elements once their position and size has already been determined, but right before they are rendered. Moving or rescaling an element with a `transform` does not affect the page disposition and leaves all other elements exactly where they would have if you hadn't applied the transform.

Comment: For future reference, it's a good idea to read articles on MDN or on the WHATWG documentation before asking questions on SO. People aren't likely to answer questions to those who have barely done any research here.